# What vimrc settings to speed up scrolling?

Tags: vim

I use gvim pretty heavily at work, typically logged into a server farm.  This works great while I'm directly on the corporate LAN, but when I VPN in from home and resume my sessions, gvim scrolls almost intolerably slow.

Every time I page up or down, the scrolling does a lot of unnecessary screen refreshes before it gets to the final spot.

I remember browsing other people's vimrc's and seeing a setting to help with this, but I don't remember what it is.  I have ttyfast already set.  Is there anything else?

I know this is mostly due to the VPN, but with a little tweaking, hopefully it can get better.

Comment: Wait, GVIM scrolls intolerably slow? Is GVIM running on your home computer or are you use remote desktop and running GVIM on the other computer?

Comment: Worse...I'm at home in Texas, logging into a VPN gateway in Kansas, to get to a server farm in Milpitas, CA.  The gvim and all the rest of my tools are running on the server farm in Cali.  

It is a lot faster when I'm at work, I'm guessing because there's no hop to Kansas, and I'm directly on the corporate backbone there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try the different tips given in `:help slow-terminal`.

For instance, the `scrolljump` setting can help reduce the number of screen refresh when scrolling. I have also found `set nowrap`to be useful, even on fast terminal when handling files with very long lines.

Answer (score 11):

If you're not doing this already, you should at least be using `CTRL+U` and `CTRL+D` to scroll around, and I believe you can use the '`scroll`' option to make `CTRL+U` and `CTRL+D` scroll a custom distance.

Answer (score 4):

If possible, I would consider using console vim. Easier to pull over multiple hops.

Answer (score -5):

Another non-vimrc technique to consider is Windows Control Panel:

[image: search on 'performance' in Control Panel]
[image: Select radio button 'Adjust for best performance']